# Modify model names during simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I 'insert' a model from the Gazebo GUI, it seems I could not change its model name anymore. Is there any way to change its name after drag it into the simulation world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14188/modify-model-names-during-simulation/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wicked88](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2759/wicked88/) on 2016-08-20**:
Hey winston. I managed to change the name internally using Entity::SetName inside a model plugin. On the other hand, the gzclient doesn't update the name and when i delete one model using gzclient's graphically way of deleting a model, the model disappears but it doesn't disappear from the world's model list ...

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-09-13**:
but like.... why? why are you relying on model name, and why do you want it to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, I don't think it's a good idea to change a model's name after it's been spawned. There's a lot of internal code which assumes the name stays the same. You can see by the [comment](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8f65af9d519d70e03a8f7ea99f669d140001d7d3/gazebo/physics/Entity.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#Entity.cc-145) on the `Entity::SetName` function. I can imagine all the topics staying the same and so on...

As a side note, every model has a unique id, but that's more meant to be a way to lookup faster (comparing ints instead of strings), than a way to keep track of a model if its name changes.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TwoBid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2562/twobid/) on 2016-09-05**:
Sorry I cant really understand that behavior. When the API gives me the option to change the name of a model, then it should have influence on all other aspects. To restart the GzClient is really unsatisfying!

I also wanted to change the model name due to some custom algorithms in the load method, so the numbering is for me important. Do I really have to adjust my algorithm because Im not able to change the name that its indicating the model instance number?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-13**:
I agree with you. I think the API call shouldn't be there if it doesn't behave properly.

**Comment by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on 2016-11-11**:
I think it is good if Gazebo provides a built-in command line tool that enables use to spawn a model with custom name, pose, orientation or etc. Then I don't have to change its name, pose, etc. after I drag it into the world.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-12**:
The `gz model` tool should do it, try `gz model -f ~/.gazebo/models/beer/model.sdf -x 1 -y 2 -z 3 -R 0.1 -P -0.3 -m my_beer` for example